# Need to set currency from environment file

Tags: environment-variables

Should I use doller sign for currency in all site from env? 
Is it good practice to use it from env?

Comment: What parameter exactly do you want to set? Dollar signs has different meanings in environment setting, and in environments for different apps.

Comment: I want to display currency for different country..I will make separate build for different country. so I want set from env variable